# Can't boot USB on Eee PC Model 1018p

Tags: windows, wubi

I have installed 12.04 via WUBI because my computer does not have a CD Drive. Is there any way that I can delete Windows 7 from my computer and use the whole HD for Ubuntu? I ask this question because for one reason or another I cannot boot from a boot-able USB stick (either in Windows or Ubuntu, however the USB port works because I am able to use my cell phone's tethering plan using all the USB ports to connect to the Internet).

Edit: Just found out the problem. Eee PC Model 1018p's do not boot from any format other than FAT and FAT16 and not FAT32.

Comment: Did you enable `boot from USB` in `BIOS`. "for one reason or another I can not boot from a bootable USB stick (either in Windows or Ubuntu"

Comment: I did enable boot from USB in the BIOS, but to no avail. Asus support could not help me, so I thought that perhaps there was a solution that I was missing.

Comment: Do you have the latest `BIOS` installed. You can go to asus page on your computer to see if there has been an update

Comment: Everything on the Asus side is updated to the latest updates, that was step #1 from Asus. Step #2 from them was basically the 'oh well, we can not help you'.

Comment: Eee Pc Model 1018P.

Comment: Could you go into `Boot` in the `Bios` and make `removable device` 1st, and disable the rest

Comment: Just found out the problem. Eee PC Model 1018p's do not boot from any format other than FAT and FAT16 and not FAT32. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the WUBI install to make a bootable LiveUSB with Startup Disk Creator.  You will be able to boot off the USB but you might need to consult the manual.  There's often a short-cut key (for example  on the EeePC) that is the easiest way to get a boot menu to boot off the USB.

Comment: The problem was right in front of my face - my Eee PC (Model 1018p) will not boot from USB using any file format other than FAT and FAT16. I used FAT32. I am sorry for posting this question, I feel silly now.

Comment: Don't feel sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Could you go into `Boot` in the `Bios` and make `removable device` 1st, and disable the rest of the boot device priorities.

Hope this can work for you!